# Как подключить CSS в JSP при использовании MVC resources

Tags: java, css, mvc, jsp

Здравствуйте, я никак не могу подключить файл CSS к JSP странице.
Пробовал много разных видов линков в head'e, пробовал при помощи библиотеки jstl/core.
Файл тупо не подтягиваеться.
Аннотация присутствует. Прикрепил структуру проекта.
Что нужно изменить в аннотации или как в JSP правильно задать путь к файлу CSS.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"  location="/resources/" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В аннотации ничего менять не нужно, у вас CSS файл не там лежит. Он должен находиться в `src/webapp/resources`. В JSP обязательно указывать ссылку в учетом Context Path.

Comment: Заработало, спасибо.
Странно но почему-то Maven проект именно такую структуру каталога делает.

Comment: Maven все создает правильно. В каталоге `src/main/resources` обычно хранят конфигурационные файлы и ресурсы, которые в дальнейщем попадают classpath приложения. Это авторы документации или  обучающих статей не знаю зачем назвали папку, где хранятся **статические ресурсы** также - `resources`, чем и смущают новичков - не вы первый. Переобзовите ее `static` или `assets`, чтобы не путаться.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, переименовал в static.
Можете пожалуйста глянуть еще один мой вопрос?
ссылка - http://goo.gl/ScebPJ

Answer (score 1):

У меня была та же проблема ... 
Решил добавив

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Также указал период кэширования для браузера ... Но до разных браузеров доходит по-разному: до FF сразу дошло а до хрома минут через 10.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="10"/>
```

Также поменял конфигурацию:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">
```